# Rolling window AR(2)-GARCH(1,1) VaR intuition query

Tags: self-study, forecasting, garch, moving-window

I have an AR(2)-GARCH(1,1) model and I need to use a 1-day rolling window 1 -step ahead forecasts to calculate the 5% conditional VaR.

I know how to calculate the VaR for 1-step ahead only - I calculate the 1 step ahead conditional mean & the 1 step ahead conditional variance. I then calculate the quantile & then I multiply that value by the initial investment to get the VaR for the 1-day ahead forecast.

But I dont really understand the concept of rolling window forecasts & how I could build the forecast let alone analysis it - I have 500 observations in sample & 500 observations out sample of stock returns. Does rolling window forecasts mean I will have 500 1-step ahead VaR figures? Which doesn't make sense to me...would I be using the same dollar investment amount each day? Furthermore what is the point of calculating a rolling 1-step ahead VaR figures & having 500 out of sample VaR forecasts?

I guess in a nutshell I am trying to understand 1 - what my output would look like and 2 - how would an analyst in practice use/analyze this method of calculating VaR.

Thanks all

Comment: The [tag:var] tag is for Vector Autoregression (VAR) rather than Value at Risk (VaR).

Comment: You might want to check other questions tagged with [tag:moving-window] and probably with [tag:garch] and [tag:forecasting]. I remember there being some similar ones to yours.

Comment: How is it going? Did you find what you were looking for?